# Exporting an Oracle table show unrecognize symbols for local(Bangla) language data in insert statement

Tags: oracle, export, local

I am exporting a table that contains some Bangla information. If I run select statement data is showing fine but if export it as select UTF-8 or UTF8 encoding this is showing some unrecognize symbol. if I choose some different encoding it shows "???" instead of Bangla letter.

what I am missing. Please help.

Oracle DB : Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production

Sql developer : Java(TM) Platform 1.8.0_291 Oracle IDE 21.2.1.204.1703 Versioning Support 21.2.1.204.1703

Addes some screenshot below.

[image]

Select query showing bangla data fine. But...
[image]

After exporting using sql developer using UTF8 or UTF-8 its showing unrecognise characters.

Comment: Have you ever tried the encoding option which is coming from `SELECT value FROM nls_database_parameters WHERE parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'` during the export ?

Comment: How are you exporting this script? What buttons/menus are you clicking on in SQL Developer to create the script?

Comment: SELECT value FROM nls_database_parameters WHERE parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET' return "AL32UTF8" but there is no "AL32UTF8" option but i use UTF8 and still no luck.

Comment: I am exporting using sql developer by right-clicking on the table and select Export option.

Comment: Does [this](http://www.sqlsnippets.com/en/topic-13430.html) help you to handle the current issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankfully those data are exported successfully! previously I right-clicked on the table and select export option then a window came up. where I had to choose encoding option.which was giving the issues with data.
[image]

But this time I selected compressed check box option from the window. It creates a zip file and inside that found the script. and wow! my data is showing fine!
[image]

Now it's working!
[image]